# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xad'

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8

```
def pair(n, num_list):
    """function receives a list of numbers and a number(n) and returns a list of numbers which are the sum of n"""
    sum_list=[]
    num_list = [int(i) for i in num_list]
    for i in num_list:
        for j in num_list:
            if (i+j) == n:
                sum_list.append ([i,j])
    if range(len(sum_list)) == 0:
        return None
    return sum_list

num_list=["­2","3","7","11","2","6"]
num_list = [int(i) for i in num_list]
print(pair(5,num_list))
```

I'm getting the next message:

> SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xad' in file
>   C:/ex3/dsfdsf.py on line 14, but no encoding declared

I'm suppose to get: `[2,3],[7,-2]`

Comment: is this all the code that you have? and is this the same file that is stated in the error? ie`C:/ex3/dsfdsf.py`

Comment: yes i took this function out of a bigger program i am on and opened a new file the check it out, when i delete the last 3 lines it doesnt give me that error, but then i cant check if the function actually works

Answer (score 1):

That error is from having a source file with non-ASCII that is not saved in UTF-8 encoding and does not have a `#coding:` statement at the top of the file delaring the encoding.  Since I don't see non-ASCII in your source on line 14 or anywhere, this must not be the exact source causing the problem.

Comment: if i delete the last 3 lines it works but then i cant check if the function actually works

Comment: @david007killer what you say confirms Mark's answer: the problem is the source code you didn't post (those last three lines)

Comment: i found the error i copied paste somthing and python thought it was ascii tnx for the help